# Change port for Fresh (Deno) webserver

Tags: deno, freshjs

My server keeps listening to port 8000, even after I’ve modified the main.tsx to include:

```
await start(manifest, { port: 3000 });
```

Comment: Any feedback? Does it work now?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have added that line after the existing

```
await start(manifest, { render });
```

Then it doesn't work. Instead modify the existing line to

```
await start(manifest, { render, port: 3000 });
```

I did it after the server was started with

```
deno task start
```

and got

> Watcher File change detected! Restarting!
> Server listening on http://localhost:3000